# How do I use the parameters in the RosinRammlerDistribution to adjust the profile for particle injection

Tags: normal-distribution, particle-system, skew, data-tracing

I am trying to use the RosinRammlerDistribution in a lagrangian kinematic solution of injecting particles into an air stream, viz.

```
                RosinRammlerDistribution
            {
                minValue        5e-04;
                maxValue        0.0012;
                d               7.5e-05;
                n               0.5;
            }
```

Where the minValue and maxValue are the minimum and maximum diameters of the particles being injected, and d, as I understand it, is the mean diameter value.  The parameter n is described as the 'shape' factor, but what is its range?  What does varying it in a positive direction mean?  What are values of d and n would produce a skewed profile towards the smaller particles?  I've explored this a little bit, but each run showing 5 seconds of injection is costing me up to 2 hours on a fairly decent machine.  Also, I cannot find an equation called or related to RosinRammler in the literature that uses a set of parameters like this so I can't do a simple plot of the equation for various parameters.  The equation that this is actually using with these parameters would be appreciated, or some guidance on changing d and n to skew the profile would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimentation with information I finally traced down from:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

[image: Plot showing effect of changing the shape parameter]